# Is it possible to request runtime permission from a dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-permissions

I just wanted to know if there is a way to request runtime permission from a dialog since the `requestPermission()` function is not available there.

I already tried to use the `context` to call this function, but it does not work either

Comment: Can you share your code you have done?

Comment: It should not be an issue. Any Android component should be able to do this. Android compomnents are: ```Activity```, ```Service```, ```BroadcastReceiver```, ```ContentProvider```, ```Fragment```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

```
public class PermissionDialog extends Dialog {
private Activity mActivity;

public PermissionDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    mActivity = (Activity) context;
}

public void requestPermission() {
    if (mActivity != null) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION}, YOUR_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private PermissionDialog mPermissionDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ...

    mPermissionDialog = new PermissionDialog(this);

    showDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPermissionDialog.requestPermission();
        }
    });
}
```

}